# How to restrict access to some properties or classes in ASP.NET Web API OData?

Tags: asp.net-web-api-odata

I have class:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I have WebAPI OData Controller:

```
public class PeopleController : ODataController
{
    [Queryable]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return (new MyEfContext()).People;
    }
}
```

Also I have in global.asax the next code:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
            routeName: "MainModelQueryOdata",
            routePrefix: "query/main",
            model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(),
            pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
            batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer),
            routingConventions: conventions);
```

I want to hide property BirthDate from non-administrators and when current user is not that Person.
How to better achieve it in ASP.NET WebAPI OData? I have CurrentUserId to compare with person.Id and I have CurrentUserIsAdmin flag to check.
The problem is that I cannot add condition to Odata Model through modelBuilder as there is not support for such behavior - I can only completely remove entity or property for everybody, but I need to show it to Administrators and people themselfes.

Comment: you want to restrict from the actual Person CLass level?  if this is WebApi then don't you have some sort of business logic level with something like getPerson() where you can write this logic?

Comment: This is not pure WebAPI, but OData. I willl add code to my post to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ***Dynamic Model*** is what you need.

Check this sample code:
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation/ReadMe.txt

Comment: Wow! Really! Thank you! However I think that performance will be not that good, need to test this approach... And also I have to move to OData v4, but it's not the big problem.

Comment: the link dont work anymore, and I was not able to find the now link